# Removing all spesific value in string of number in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, replace

I want to remove all "0" in my string, not only the first same value, any suggest?

Why its work but just only the first code

```js
var str = "90807005"

console.log(str.replace("0",""))
```

I try to read another source and say to use (/"something"/g, new) for change all same value, and its still not working

```js
var str = "90807005"

console.log(str.replace(/"0"/g,""))
```

I want it to be str = "9875";

Comment: When a  method doesn't do what you think it should is the time to go thoroughly read the documentation for that method

Comment: yah, i'm sorry, i should read clearly and better the documentation, thanks for the advice :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`String.replaceAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll) or a global flag in your regex:

```js
var str = "90807005"

console.log(str.replaceAll("0","")) //replaceAll
console.log(str.replace(/0/g,"")) //global flag
```

Comment: Node.js is not supported replaceAll, but the second suggestion is working very well, thanks!